How can I change the GRUB background theme in Kali Linux?
How can I get back the GRUB boot theme which changed when I upgraded the GNOME desktop environment. I am also getting a Fedora 12 image on rebooting or shutdown
This is the original theme I want back:

This is the current one:

Where can I find the full assets of my desired theme so I can replace it in the boot/grub/theme?

Search for the parameter GRUB_BACKGROUND= in the config file /etc/default/grub.cfg. You should be able to edit to any image you want using this setting.
After that, it's necessary to update grub with the new configuration, using sudo update grub or sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg

The basic solution I figured out was to run a vm instance, take the files and copy them to my machine and run sudo update-grub
link for the vm grub content: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-jyB3W8ogZK8lU-uquQqN6H8h1rGhuOp/view?usp=sharing
